# SoapClient __soapCall calls older version of a service even after clearing the cache dir

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using [BeSimpleSoap](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSoap) to send requests to WSDL based web services. One of those services updated recently. **And I can access it via SoapUI**, but when I call __soapCall with the updated function (with same URL and credentials), it throws exception:

```
SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getXXXX") is not a valid method for this service
```

**What I tried:**

- Deleted soap.wsdl_cache_dir (with rm `/tmp/wsdl-*`)
- Cleared Symfony cache

My soap config in php.ini:

```
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
```

What should I do? It keeps calling the old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out deleting `soap.wsdl_cache_dir` with `rm /tmp/wsdl-*` wasn't enough.

**Following these steps actually worked for me:**

1. Set `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 0` in php.ini
2. Restart httpd (After this, the exception became `SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '/wsdl_947060b0c026bc9194617a747e1b22ab.cache' : failed to load external entity "/wsdl_947060b0c026bc9194617a747e1b22ab.cache"`. I don't know why.)
3. Set `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 1` in php.ini
4. Restart httpd